# Complex analysis: What is the mysterious polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, integration

I am given 2 pieces of information as below:

1)A polynomial $\displaystyle P(z)=\sum_{n=0}^d a_n z^n$

2) For all $n=0,\dots,d$, $\displaystyle \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{P(z)}{(2z-1)^{n+1}} dz = 0 $

Then I am asked to find what is $P(z)$. Am I supposed to use the residue formula and get the $\mbox{residue}=0$ for all $n=0,\dots,d$?

Comment: Why not using LaTeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** As a polynomial of degree at most $d$, $P(z)$ is a linear combination of the polynomials $(2z-1)^n$ for $0\leqslant n\leqslant d$, that is, $P(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^da_n(2z-1)^n$ for some complex coefficients $a_n$.

Then, for every $0\leqslant n\leqslant d$, $\displaystyle\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{P(z)}{(2z-1)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm dz=$ $____$ by the residue theorem, hence $a_n=$ $____$ for every  $0\leqslant n\leqslant d$.

Comment: These empty little boxes are a nice way to give hints!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the hint. But I still do not get it. How to calculate the first blank? I get very clumsy when working with explicit formula. So I tried to calculate for n=0 first. I get 2(pi)(i)(a0). I'm handicapped at using Latex and it's difficult to express what I do not understand.

Comment: The residue of $P(z)/(2z-1)^{n+1}$ at $z=1/2$ is the sum of the residues of $a_k/(2z-1)^{n+1-k}$. What is the residue of $1/(2z-1)^{n+1-k}$?

Comment: I am supposed to use the "Limit formula for higher order poles" right? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)

Comment: But I get residue of 1/(2z−1)^{n+1−k} is zero.

Comment: Certainly not if n=k... Come on, do your job!

Comment: When n=k, the residue of 1/(2z−1)^{n+1−k} is 1/2. When n!=k, the residue is zero?

Comment: Therefore the first blank is $a_n(2pi)(i)(1/2)= a_n(pi)(i)$ ?